# Не запускается Linux

Tags: linux

Доброго времени уважаемые форумчане.
Возникла у меня проблема в решении которой прошу вашей помощи.
Проблема следующая: на материнской плате помер контроллер SATA, я поставил плату RAID SiI 3114, подключил к нему жесткий диск, с помощью LiveCD перенастроил fstab (UUID заменил на имена устройств), изменил в lilo.conf имя жесткого диска на /dev/sda6 (это у меня корень), но система по прежнему не стартует, выдает следующее:

[alt text](http://s016.radikal.ru/i336/1104/7e/3dea09cb2144.jpg)

Я так подозреваю, что проблема в том, что система не знает какие драйвера использовать для этого контроллера.

Прилагаю скрин разбивки HDD
[image]

Вот прилагаю fstab и lilo.conf:
**fstab**

```
proc        /proc           proc    nosuid,noexec,gid=proc      0 0
devpts      /dev/pts        devpts  nosuid,noexec,gid=tty,mode=620  0 0
tmpfs       /tmp            tmpfs   nosuid              0 0
/dev/sda6   /   ext3    relatime    1   1
/dev/sda8   /home   ext3    nosuid,relatime 1   2
/dev/sda7   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/sr0    /media/cdrom    udf,iso9660 ro,noauto,user,utf8 0 0
/dev/sda9   /opt    ext3    relatime    1   1</code></pre>  

__lilo.conf__  
<pre><code>map="/boot/map"
lba32
prompt
compact
vga="0x314"
boot="/dev/sda"
timeout="50"
install="menu"
message="/boot/splash/message"
append="resume=/dev/sda7 panic=30 splash=silent"
# default="Windows1"
default="ALTLinux"

image="/boot/vmlinuz"
    label="ALTLinux"
    initrd="/boot/initrd.img"
    root="/dev/sda6"
    read-only

image="/boot/vmlinuz"
    label="failsafe"
    initrd="/boot/initrd.img"
    root="/dev/sda6"
    addappend="failsafe"
    vga="normal"
    read-only

other="/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD3200AAKS-00V1A0_WD-WMAWF0600635-part1"
    label="Windows1"
image="/boot/memtest-4.00.bin"
    label="memtest"
image="/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.30-std-def-alt14"
    initrd="/boot/initrd-2.6.30-std-def-alt14.img"
    label="2630-std-def-14"
    root="/dev/sda6"
    read-only
    optional
image="/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-std-def-alt20.M50P.1"
    initrd="/boot/initrd-2.6.32-std-def-alt20.M50P.1.img"
    label="2632-std-def-20M50P1"
    root="/dev/sda6"
    read-only
    optional
```

Если в fstab выключить своп то возникает такая же ошибка.

Comment: кто такой /dev/sda7 ?
загрузись с лайва, создай точки монтирования, смонтируй тома вручную. так ты узнаешь, а есть ли тома на самом деле ;)

Comment: Это я все уже делал: загружался с лайва, примонтировал корневой раздел HDD изменил fstab и lilo.conf (в них изменил UUIDы на имена устройств: /dev/sda6 - /, /dev/sda7 - swp, /dev/sda8 - /home), далее сделал: 
chroot /dev/sda6
lilo

Comment: Извеняюсь, я не сразу понял ваш вопрос. /dev/sda7 это раздел своп. При загрузке с лайва эти разделы монтируются нормально и данные на них все остались прежними

Comment: какой-же это своп, если ОС говорит что его нет. проверь еще раз, может что напутал.

Comment: Добавил скрин разметки HDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простите за нескромный вопрос. Вы хорошо выполняли /sbin/lilo? Если нет, то загрузитесь, например, с CD-диска в GNU/linux и далее попробуйте следующее:

1. Выполнить mount без парамeтров (запоминаем все виртуальные файловые системы proc, sys, dev...).
2. Монтируем ваш корень на /mnt, подмонтируем к /mnt все ваши разделы, которые у вас монтируется при нормальной загрузке к корню (то есть /home, например, у вас должен стать /mnt/home). С виртуальными файловыми системами поступаем почти аналогично, но иначе монтируем точки монтирования к каталогам внутри /mnt, то бишь с proc поступаем вот так:
   **`mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`** и по такому принципу с каждой виртуальной файловой системой.
3. Делаем подмену корня: **`chroot /mnt`**. Теперь вы в своей системе, а не в life-cd.
4. Выполняем /sbin/lilo: **`lilo`**.
5. Выходим из свой системы, если больше ничего не надо (например, можно поменять lilo на GRUB): **`exit`**.
6. Отмонтируем все командой: **`umount`**.
7. Перезагружаемся: **`reboot`**.
8. Загружаемся с жесткого диска.

Comment: Ну я все так и делал, кроме того что не монтировал /home и /opt.
Но и примонтирование этих дополнительных разделов не помогло :(

Comment: Да. Давно бы пора на GRUB сменить.

Comment: Солидарен. Даешь GRUB в массы.

Comment: Что-Ж, не знаю. Бывает lilo правильно находит ядро но передает ему неверную информация о том где собственно корень, но если это не ваш случай, а нет подержки вашего контролера, то как вариант делаем все выше изложенное но перед исполнением /sbin/lilo пересобираем kernel linux для подержки вашего оборудования (нужные для загрузки компоненты можно влючить монолитно) и собираем initrd (если нужен). P.S. Так же можно добавить метку тома для вашего /dev/sda6 и вместо root=/dev/sda6 root="LABEL=ВАША_МЕТКА".

Answer (score 0):

А можно fstab? Насколько я увидел, ругается пока только на /dev/sda7. Если не монтировать Swap(т.е. sda7), начинает ругаться на следующий раздел?

Comment: Параметр resume=... используется для возврата из глубокого сна. Можно убрать если не используется. Ошибка про /dev/sda7 приходит еще во время работы загрузчика. Только вот скорее всего modal прав. Если с lilo порядок - этой проблемы не должно было быть.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с запуском решена. Решение подсказал "asy", нужно было подправить initrd. Полная версия темы [тут](http://forum.altlinux.org/index.php/topic,10449.0.html)
Всем спасибо за помощь.